# how to create a number "limit" in a range

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code, it works just fine. But I need to create a limit that is the count(in my case 10).

Can you help me with a simple solution?

```
def multiples(m, count):
    for i in range(0,count*m,m):
        print(i)
        
multiples(3, 10)
```

Comment: What's a "limit" in this context? What happens when it is reached?

Comment: `count = min(count, 10)`

Comment: when you say "it works just fine" do you mean it runs without error or it does what you want? if it does what you want what is the question, if it doesn't do what you want please elaborate on what you want `count` to accomplish

Comment: Describe what should this code do.

Comment: plz elaborate what exactly you need?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation. the code should stop at "9" so the result shouldnt be over the argument: count. It should come out 3,6,9 then nothing. @JNevill

Comment: @voidnoid: Why are you going to `count * m` if you want to stop at `count`? `range(0, count, m)` would do what you want, but I'm unclear if there is something else where you might conditionally want to allow it to go to `count * m`.

Comment: Agreeing with @ShadowRanger here. Just do `range(0, count, m)` and call it a day. No reason to over complicate things.

Comment: @voidnoid if you want 3 numbers then call it multiples(3, 3), why are you calling multiples(3, 10)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you could do the following:

```
def multiples(m, count):
    for i in range(count//m):
        print((i+1)*m)
        
multiples(3, 10)
```

The double `//` in the range would make sure that it yields an integer value of the number of times it is contained.  The print would then simply iterate through all of those multiplications.  I can give a further explanation if it isn't making sense.